# Footer at the bottom

Tags: html, css, position, footer

here's my problem, my footer dont stay at the bottom of the page.

I try anything: clear:boths;bottom:0; margin... nothing is working..

My question is: How can i put it in the bottom of the page.

HERE IS MY CODE

```
<div id = "wrapper">
       .....
       ....

   <div id = "content2">
    <div id = "fastMenu">
        <a href="conseil-d-administration">
            <img src="<?php echo 'http://dev201.viglob.gtvr.com/client_file/themes                    /default/interface/FR/menuAdmin.png'; ?>" border="0" />
        </a>
        <a href="congres-2012">
            <img src="<?php echo 'http://dev201.viglob.gtvr.com/client_file/themes/default/interface/FR/menuCongres.png'; ?>" border="0" />
        </a>
        <a href="formation">
            <img src="<?php echo 'http://dev201.viglob.gtvr.com/client_file/themes/default/interface/FR/menuFormation.png'; ?>" border="0" />
        </a>            
        <a href="devenir-membre">
            <img src="<?php echo 'http://dev201.viglob.gtvr.com/client_file/themes/default/interface/FR/menuMembre.png'; ?>" border="0" />
        </a>            
    </div>  
    <div id="contenu" class="txt">          
        </div>   <?php //CONTENU2 ?>  
      <div id = "leftSide">
        <?php  include_once(INC_PATH_FULL_THEME.'event-teaser.php'); ?>
      </div>          
   </div>  <?php //CONTENT2 ?>   
     <div id = "footer">

       </div>
```

CSS

```
#footer{
width: 900px;
height: 100px;
background:white;
margin-top: 100px;    
bottom: 0;
clear:both;    
 }
  #contenu2{
background:white;
width: 600px;
float:right;
padding-right: 2.5%;
 z-index: 1;
 }
 #content2{
width: 900px;
height: auto;
margin-left: 1px;
background:white;
overflow: auto;
z-index: 1;
position:absolute;
   }

#wrapper{
width:900px;    
align: 26.5%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 15px;
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, Verdana;
 }
```

Comment: Do you want the footer to stay at the bottom of the screen or at the bottom of your content?
`position:fixed; bottom:0;` will push the footer to the bottom of the screen but other content will not affect the footer's position

Comment: @potench i want to put it at bottom : 0; :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/tTCbp/)**

When am formatting your code on `jsfiddle`, I have come across few issues and fixed those:-

1. On HTML, closing `div` is missing
2. On CSS, removed number 2 from a class `"#contenu2"` (Now it is `"#contenu"`)
3. Added `position: absolute;` to the `#footer` class

### HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content2">
        <div id="fastMenu">
            <a href="conseil-d-administration">
                <img src="<?php echo 'http://dev201.viglob.gtvr.com/client_file/themes                    /default/interface/FR/menuAdmin.png'; ?>" border="0" />
            </a>
            <a href="congres-2012">
                <img src="<?php echo 'http://dev201.viglob.gtvr.com/client_file/themes/default/interface/FR/menuCongres.png'; ?>" border="0" />
            </a>
            <a href="formation">
                <img src="<?php echo 'http://dev201.viglob.gtvr.com/client_file/themes/default/interface/FR/menuFormation.png'; ?>" border="0" />
            </a>            
            <a href="devenir-membre">
                <img src="<?php echo 'http://dev201.viglob.gtvr.com/client_file/themes/default/interface/FR/menuMembre.png'; ?>" border="0" />
            </a>            
        </div>  
        <div id="contenu" class="txt">          
        </div>   <?php //CONTENU2 ?>  
        <div id="leftSide">
        <?php  include_once(INC_PATH_FULL_THEME.'event-teaser.php'); ?>
        </div>          
    </div>  <?php //CONTENT2 ?>
    <div id="footer">
        FooterText
    </div>      
</div>
​
```

### CSS:

```
#footer {
    width: 900px;
    height: 100px;
    background:white;
    margin-top: 100px;    
    bottom: 0;
    clear:both;    
    position: absolute;
}

#contenu {
    background:white;
    width: 600px;
    float:right;
    padding-right: 2.5%;
    z-index: 1;
}

#content2 {
    width: 900px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 1px;
    background:white;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    position:absolute;
}

#wrapper{
    width:900px;    
    align: 26.5%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, Verdana;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting your footer to always be at the bottom of the page unless pushed down by content, check out [this sticky footer tutorial](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/). The following code should be all you need.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">    
    </div>
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

/*

Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait
http://ryanfait.com/

*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add to your css:

```
position: relative;
```

to element which contain `footer` element.

and of course `position: absolute` for `footer` element.

in your case:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: How position relative can burn all your stuff?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Try to adapt it to your code. Sign as an answer if it's helpful.

```
html, body {
    margin:0 auto; /* to center page align (can be left, right)*/
    height:100%;
}

#container {  /* contains everything, footer inclusive. */
    min-height:100%; 
    position:relative; 
}

#footer {
    clear: both;  
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0; 
    height:55px; /*Required, Height of the footer */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put "Position:absolute;" in the footer css. 
JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sdxaZ/