# how to use Div relative height 100%?

Tags: css, html, web, height

I am a beginner in website design. I would like to have a dynamic height of content. So I do something like this:

```
<div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;" id="content">
    ....
</div>

<div style="position:relative;width:2000px;height:498px;">
    <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
</div>
```

However the div of footer does not detect the height of content. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Refer this **[Footer at the bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146121/footer-at-the-bottom)**

Comment: Read this article [Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

Comment: Try removing width and height, maybe that works.

Answer (score 1):

you can use JQuery for passing height to an element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var hgt = $(window).height();
$("#content").css({"height" : hgt });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the height of the content as 100% so that is probably why it does not detect the height of content as content would try to fit to 100% height

try using

```
<div style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;width:2000px;height:498px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea of doing that using css, and I don't think css would detect the dieght of screen or something.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var sch=screen.height;
d = document.getElementById('content');
d.style.height=screen.height;
});
```

This should work. using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Hey use this link to align your CSS. Make Changes what Ryan Fait Said.

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

You can find the CSS here,

[http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/layout.cs](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/layout.css)s

and here is how you use it,

http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/